# How to export pageviews from google analytics user explorer

Tags: google-analytics

I was able to get the User Explorer to show the user id my system provides google analytics as shown below:

[image]

However, the problem is that I need to click into each user to be able to see all the page views for that specific user.  Is there a way to export a CSV of all the pageviews for all the users without having to click into each user individually? In other words, I want a CSV to have a column for `Page` and a column for `User Id`.

Comment: Can't you just get that from your access log file of your server?

Comment: The website is hosted on netlify, so I'm not sure how to grab the access logs from it.

Comment: Google Analytics is not a logging service.  Analytics is rollups and graphs of user behavior.   I wouldn't expect GA to be able to do what you want, although I don't know for sure that it can't.

Comment: Thank you. I complimented the user Explorer by using custom dimension to accept userId as well.  Now, the Behaviour>Sites Content>All Pages will list all pageviews along with userId if I choose to append it as a second dimension.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately GA Standard (free version) does not provide that functionality for the User Explorer reports.

If using GA360 you do have BigQuery Export for Analytics
https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/3437618?hl=en

Comment: Thank you, I mention my alternative in comments above

Comment: Custom dimensions are also very handy. I use them for a variety of additional information